# rewrite shell script so that cat does not evade the check

Tags: shell, sh, cat, fifo, mkfifo

Currently, I use

```
#!/bin/sh
while [ -e "${XDG_RUNTIME_DIR}" ]; do cat ${FIFO} ; done | my_program
```

to create a fifo for my_program, which reads from stdin.

The problem is that `cat` *breaks out* of the while loop check, and the process continues after my xdg_runtime_dir does not exist anymore.

Is there a way to rewrite this, so that the check is enforced, i.e. when xdg_runtime_dir does not exist, the process terminates?

Comment: Not sure if I understand correctly. But maybe `while test -e "${XDG_RUNTIME_DIR}" && cat ${FIFO}; do sleep 1; done | my_program` works? Now if either condition is false, the loop terminates.

Comment: Ok, I've made my comment an answer and elaborated a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `while` construct can test for two commands if you chain them with `&&`:

```
while test -e "${XDG_RUNTIME_DIR}" && cat ${FIFO}; do
    sleep 1
done | my_program
```

Now if either condition is false, the loop terminates.

Note that if you want to terminate only on the *second* condition, you could use

```
while okToFail -xy; cat ${FIFO}; do ...
```

since `while` actually takes a *list* of commands, and the exit status of a list is the status of the last command.

Comment: ... But then what is the purpose of the `test -e` at all?

Comment: @tripleee It's pretty much useless here; I just varied the command relevant to determine the list status. I've edited the answer to replace the useless `test`.